# 3 rows into 1 SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.quantity, TO_CHAR(t.price, 'L9,999,999.99') AS Total_Price
FROM a3_order_item o JOIN a3_tree t
ON (t.id = o.tree_id)
WHERE o.order_id = '00000072'
GROUP BY o.quantity, o.order_id, t.price
```

The Output is:

```
ORDER_ID   QUANTITY TOTAL_PRICE            
-------- ---------- -----------------------
00000072          2                 £47.00 
00000072          1                 £34.20 
00000072          1                 £23.00
```

Is there a way to combine these rows into 1 row like this:

```
ORDER_ID   QUANTITY TOTAL_PRICE            
-------- ---------- -----------------------
00000072          4                 £107.20
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT o.order_id, sum(o.quantity), TO_CHAR(sum(t.price), 'L9,999,999.99') AS Total_Price
FROM a3_order_item o JOIN a3_tree t
ON (t.id = o.tree_id)
WHERE o.order_id = '00000072'
GROUP BY  o.order_id
```